# Access httpd on virtual centos

Tags: centos, httpd, virtualbox

I am running a centos7 instance using Virtualbox. The host machine is running Debian 9.

My centos machine is running fine and using one host only network, I am able to ping it or ssh into it from the host, I have also set up a NAT-network to allow the virtual instance access to internet.

Everything is fine so far. I then installed httpd and tried to access it from the host, using the same IP as I use for ssh, but, I am not able to connect to the virtual machine. From a shell on the virtual machine "curl localhost" works fine, so the httpd it self seems to be working.

I have tried to set both Listen 80 and listen host-only-ip:80 in httpd.conf.

I am not able to see the attempted access from the host in any of the logs, so it seems it is blocked before it comes to the httpd - is there a default firewall rule that should block incoming on port 80, or can there be some other things I have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

You need [HOST Only adapter](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) or [port forwarding](https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) since [NAT](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) disallow you from contacting anything behind `virtual` router.

Comment: As written, I have set up a host only network - that works fine for ssh and ping, but http doesn't work, so something else is going on - this may be more of a centos than a virtualbox problem.